# Intersection of nested sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have set $A = \{1,3,5,7\}$ and set $B = \left\{\{1\},\{3\},\{3,5\},\{5,7\}\right\}$
What would $A\cap B$ be?

Comment: Hey, welcome to MathSE :) Use the dollar symbol to write in math-mode, for which this guide is quite handy! https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: yeah sorry, this is my first time using this.

Comment: No sweat - we were all first-time users at some point! :) 

With regards to your question, I think that the intersection is empty, since set $A$ is a set whose entries are numbers, and set $B$ is a set of sets - since the elements of $B$ are sets themselves.

Comment: If $x \in A\cap B$, then $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. $x$ that satisfies $x \in A$ are 1, 3, 5, 7; none of them are a member of $B$, for example, $1 \not \in B$. Note that $\{1\} \in B$; this is different from $1 \not \in B$.

Comment: Oh alright, I see. Thank you for your answers, and also sorry for not stating the question properly. Thank you for the edits @JeremyJeffreyJames

Comment: $A\cap B$ is the empty set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would extend my comment above as an answer.

The intersection of $A$ and $B$ is empty, since there is no element of $A$ which is also an element of $B$.

Whilst symbolically it might seem like there are several commonalities between the two sets, we need to note that the set $A = \{1,3,5,7\}$ is a set comprised of *scalars*, whilst the set $B = \left\{\{1\},\{3\},\{3,5\},\{5,7\}\right\}$ is a set comprised of *sets* of scalars.

As noted by 'dust05', $x\in A\cap B\iff x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Since we regard $\{x\}$ as being *wholly* distinct an entity to just $x$, it's then clear that there exists no $x\in A$ which also satisfies $x\in B$. The former is the *set*, comprised solely of the element $x$, whereas the latter is just the element $x$.